# Select alphabetic only strings of three characters length

Tags: sql, regex, database, oracle

I have a field in my table that is a varchar and contains alphabetic, numeric, and mixed alphanumeric values.

I would like to select only the values from that field which are 3 characters in length and alphabetic only.

I am using oracle.

Sample Data:

```
AAA
BBB
12345
CCC25
DDDDD
```

The select statement should only return:

```
AAA
BBB
```

I tried the following and it didn't work. This did not return anything.

```
select name from MyTable where name like '[a-Z][a-Z][a-Z]';
```

Then I tried the following thinking it would return all 3-characters long results and it just returned everything:

```
select name from MyTable where name like '%%%';
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `regexp_like` function

```
SQL> with x as (
  2    select 'aaa' str from dual union all
  3    select 'bbb' from dual union all
  4    select '12345' from dual union all
  5    select 'CCC25' from dual union all
  6    select 'DDDDD' from dual
  7  )
  8  select *
  9    from x
 10   where regexp_like( str, '^[[:alpha:]]{3}$' );

STR
-----
aaa
bbb
```

Comment: Does that mean I have to write a select statement for each values in the table, like you did above in line 2-6? I have thousands of rows(64000 to be precise).

Comment: it's just example. use code from select where x is your tablename and str your column

Comment: @javaStudent - You can query whatever table you have directly (either getting rid of the `WITH` clause entirely or replacing the query I wrote with a query against the actual table).  Since we don't have access to your tables or your data, the simplest way to show the query working is to put together a `WITH` subquery that manually assembles the data you actually gave us.

Comment: Thank you. I spent almost two hours trying to figure this out.